# How to capture screen in a real device for KIF

Tags: ios, screenshot, kif

As you see, the KIF screenshots feature won’t work when runs on actual devices if the directory you’ve specified is outside of the app sandbox, but how to set KIF_SCREENSHOTS(the environment parameter) to a sandbox folder?

Comment: From phatmann, using NSLog on the device to print the path to the folder you want to use, then hard code that path into KIF_SCREENSHOTS.